# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have UserID: number in my user.model.ts file and i have function to reset my form in user.component.ts.
`

```
resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form!=null)
    form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      UserID : null,
      UserName: '',
      Password: '',
      confirmPass: '',
      FirstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      UserRole: ''
    }
  }
```

`
I got error in UserID : null, Type null is not assignable to type 'number' .How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to hustle with such errors u can set
"strictNullChecks": false,
in the compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type of userId to

```
userID?: number;
```

or to

```
userID: null | number;
```

in your service

Comment: wouldn't `null | number` be typescript?

Comment: You are already writing code in typescript file right?

Comment: Oh. FSR my brain thought this question was javascript and not typescript. Apologies for the derp!